# VBscript for netstat filtering only listening ports

Tags: vbscript

Why does the script below not work when I plug in "netstat -an | find ""LISTENING""" for the command?

```
set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")  
call GetConnections()  

Function GetConnections()  
  i = 0  
  set shExec = sh.Exec("netstat -an")  
   Do While Not shExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream  
      Wscript.Echo shExec.StdOut.ReadLine()  
  Loop  
End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`|` (and `<`, `>`, `>>`) are implemented by cmd.exe. It has no meaning to any other program.

So get cmd.exe to run your program.

```
set shExec = sh.Exec("cmd /c netstat -an|find something")
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!